# when I run flutter code in macOS then the downloable data error

Tags: flutter

## Launching lib/main_dev.dart on macOS in debug mode

authentication = virtual;

category = simulator;

contentType = diskImage;

dictionaryVersion = 2;

fileSize = 7354535384;

hostRequirements ={

minHostVersion = "13.4";

minXcodeVersion = "15.0";

};identifier = "com.apple.dmg.xrSimulatorSDK1_0_b1";

name = "xrOS 1 beta Simulator Runtime";

platform = "com.apple.platform.xros";

simulatorVersion =     {

buildUpdate = 21N5165g;

version = "1.0";

};
source="https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/visionOS_1_beta/visionOS_1_beta_Simulator_Runtime.dmg";

version = "1.0.0.1";

},

NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to read in downloadable data. See underlying errors for details., DVTUnderlyingErrorsKey=(
"Error Domain=DVTDownloadableErrors Code=23 "'com.apple.platform.xros' is an unknown platform identifier." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription='com.apple.platform.xros' is an unknown platform identifier.}")}File "build/macos/Build/Products/Debug Dev/Runner.app" does not exist.
Unable to find executable to run
Error launching application on macOS.
what I do to solve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.